# Export Layers to Files exports only 4 png files from 100 layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to export my layers to png files.

Googling suggests that `File` → `Script` → `Export Layers to Files…` is suitable.

However, this takes ages to complete and for some reason it exports only 4 images out of 100 layers.

Why?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds too elementary, but are you sure you have "Visible layers only" unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

The speed of course is mainly dependent on two things really -- the actual size of the file (consequently, the size of each layer) and the amount of processing power your computer has. Naturally, the more processing power you have the bigger files you can work with without noticing a deterioration in performance.

Unfortunately you haven't provided too much information about the exact file, so I can only guess. So either you're working with an incredibly large file or there's something else the matter.

I personally have never used `Export Layers to Files...` on anything as tasking as 100 layers, but it should work just as well on 20 layers as it should on 100.

I've done batch processes on 800+ images, and though it takes it's time, each image took maybe half a second, and those images are about 3.5 MB average and I have 4.00GB of RAM.

Have you tried restarting Photoshop, and rerunning the script?

Comment: Additional test info: I just did a 1280px square image with noise fill, 100 identical layers. The PSD file is 390MB. What the script does is duplicates the image twice, hides all layers except one, flattens the image, saves, then closes and reduplicates first image duplicate. This means that you need enough memory available to have all three images open. Photoshop uses a about a Gig of memory during this operation. Oddly, the two duplicates don't triple the memory usage: PS first open: 140MB; with file: 970MB;  during op: 990MB