# How to avoid sequence numbers when exporting layers in Photoshop CC2015?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, photoshop-scripting, cc-2015

I am using Photoshop CC2015 to modify and then export layers as files. While saving, Photoshop automatically adds a number sequence to the file.

I do not want this numbering. All I want is *'prefix_layername.jpg'*, not *'prefix_0001_layername.jpg'*.

I've read [a thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10669/cs5-export-layers-as-files-no-number-sequence) which described a solution for CS5, but this doesn't seem to work for CC2015. I understand we need to edit the 'Export Layers To Files.jsx' which is located at:

/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC 2015/Presets/Scripts

Can someone give me the changes that need to be made at this file to avoid the numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5 on a Mac.

1. On a Mac, go to Applications > Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5 > Presets > Scripts > Export Layers To Files.jsx
2. Open the .jsx file and comment out the the contents of line 1083 by applying two forward slash characters (//) to the beginning of the line. The resulting code will look like this:

   ```
   // fileNameBody += "_" + zeroSuppress(i, 4);
   ```
3. Save the .jsx file changes.
4. Close and reopen Photoshop CC, then run File > Export > Layers to Files...

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly, except there is underscore "_". Any idea on getting rid of that. I am using PSD CC 2018

Comment: In PSD CC 2018 you can remove the underscore that is generated between the file name and the "Layer" name by doing the following:
1) search for this line of code (in my file it was at line 2195):
fileNameBody += "_" + layerName;
2) change the underscore character between the quote marks to a space character (or whatever character you prefer):
fileNameBody += " " + layerName;
When you run the script the underscore between the file name and layer name will become a space character.