# Exporting photoshop layers to PNG in cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, export, cs6

I've seen the response [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process), but the built-in script is excruciatingly slow (I let it sit for 3 hours before giving up) and the custom one in the response thinks there's only one layer (and only exports one PNG). What are my options?

EDIT: I actually want to save each layer to a separate PNG, not export the current visible layers to a single PNG.

Comment: how large is the file your working with? - it could help to save a new version of your psd with the layers flattened then save as a png

Comment: The file is 52.5mb. Your comment makes me realize my question wasn't very clear though - I actually want to save each layer to a separate PNG.

Comment: ahh, you may be able to create (or find/buy) an action that isolates a layer then saves it out as a png, then goes back and so on until all the layers have been saved - sorry I cant think of an easy way

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing exactly. If you are a mac user and don't mind spending a little money, maybe this is exactly what you want: http://macrabbit.com/slicy/ If that is exactly what you want and you are windows user, I don't think there's anything quite like Slicy, for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the original author of the script linked through OP's post and in an effort to give this question some closure, I'd like to say that most likely the document that Fibericon was trying to save had some layer groups which my original script couldn't handle. It has since been updated.

The script can be found linked [through my answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1962/408), or it can be downloaded [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!89hkGKKQ!c-Xq_nOmFOp2AoC1_co3-CWrt6s_xdZLbcWeTpmuauQ). I just updated it yesterday and should be a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CS5, but it should be about the same. Please Try:

File -> Scripts -> Export Layers To Files

Comment: Yes, that's the built in script that I described as being excruciatingly slow.

Answer (score 0):

I have my my own "Layer Saver" script for Photoshop CS3 or better here..
http://www.ps-bridge-scripts.talktalk.net/