# Export Photoshop layers in subfolder to individual files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, batch-processing

My question is an extension from this question ( [Batch export Photoshop layers to individual PNG files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process) ), but for some reason, I can't seem to contact any of the posters from that thread.

Basically, I want to do that same process, but instead of just doing the top layers, I want to do the layers that are inside a folder. The reason for this is because I have several base layers, that don't change. Actually, all that is changing in mine is some text. So is there a way to add a dropdown that would allow me to choose which subfolder I want to use as the layers to alternate?

Naturally, I want to adapt escalation746's script, as it is the fastest.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey David, I'm the original author of the script. You could have contacted me through a comment there. It doesn't appear as if escalation746 is still around. I'd be happy to update his script (which is based on my script) and try and add such a feature into it. I'm currently at work but I'll try and take a look at it when I get home but I don't see why it's not possible.

Comment: I need a reputation of 50 to comment, otherwise I would have done just that.
And sounds good, thank you.

Comment: Have you made any headway on this?

Comment: Actually working on it right now. Just started early today and I have a four day weekend so I'll be working on it and ironing it out. I've found some problems with escalation746's script (it doesn't seem to save each layer individually) so I'm trying to fix a few things and improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David,

[I've completed the script](https://mega.co.nz/#!l9J2QS4L!CopOvAqfLk1TAAOFeeMb5Hs5zAEtzhzDFlmPVSbSxiI). I added a dropdown that allows you to choose to export all layers or just a specific layer group. Please note that it only picks up top-level layer groups right now, and I haven't done extensive testing on how it will handle nested groups (though it should handle it just fine).

Let me know if this does everything you need it to or if you need any other functionality with it.

**EDIT**

Just wanted to add the link to the most up-to-date version of [the script here](https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast).

Comment: Finally got a chance to test it out, and it works... kinda. It seems to be working as before, where it will save all layers, but instead of only touching the folder selected, it's hiding everything. So I'm still only getting those layers in the folder selected, instead of the layers in the folder selected, and everything else.

Make sense?

Comment: Oh you want to select specific layers, not specific layer groups? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: No, you did it right, but, say I have a background layer, and then a layer group that has five text layers. The output should be five files, with the text alternating and the background staying. However, yours just outputs the five text layers, and the background is invisible.

Comment: To be honest that seems to ruin the whole point of exporting layers to images (as it's implied that every layer be a unique image.) And while I do see how this functionality might be useful to you it seems too localized for me at the moment to invest any more time into it for now as my time is rather limited. I would suggest building some actions perhaps that automatically save the layer your own and all layers underneath it.

Comment: Perhaps seeing my project will help. ( http://meesa94.deviantart.com/art/KJV-Album-Art-373478919 ) As you can see, I have 66 different text layers that need to be switched out. Run your script, and you'll see what happens compared to what it should look like.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what my script is meant to do.

Comment: Perhaps, but I modified it to my needs by commenting out lines 53 and 56 (For anybody who wants to do what I wanted).
Can you post you answer as a real answer, so I can mark this as solved?