# Export photoshop layers programatically to individual pngs of different sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, png

Hi there I'm trying to export all of the layers in my `.psd` to `.pngs`/`.jpegs` and I am having trouble exporting them so that the sizes of the individual `.pngs` are the size of the image they contain.

I have seen this [thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process) which has a script that almost does this but since I'm a new user here I can't comment on it...if the creator of that script (Johannes) could respond i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using slicy. it works very well: just had to write a script to create the folders so that slicy can read the psd correctly

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of http://macrabbit.com/slicy/?  I started using this and it makes it extremely easy to export all layers as .png or .jpg. with one click.  From what I remember it makes the .png the same size as the image it contains.  Might be worth looking into.  It's made life easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Action to do this if you have a lot of layers to save. Regardless, here's what you do:

- Click on the layer in the layers palette and go under `Layer > Duplicate Layer` (you can also right click for this).
- In the dialog box that pops up, look at the bottom where it says Destination and select "New" from the drop down menu. This duplicates the layer in a new document.
- If the background of the new document is transparent, go to `Image > Trim`. Select `transparent pixels` and trim away top, bottom, left, right.

If the image had a background color, hide or delete that layer, then follow the step above. Then save the new document and then save for web.

Comment: Right now I have a script which does this but it's highly inefficient to create and close hundreds of new documents so I'm trying to find a more efficient way to do the same thing. Also I want to do this programatically not by hand

Answer (score 0):

Use this script below to save each layer into files. When you save them in seperate files you can create an action which makes the Image -> Trim move to cut the layers transparent pixels which you don't need for every file.

[You can download the script from here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8060862/layersaver.zip)

Comment: Chrome does not like that link: "***The Website Ahead Contains Malware!***" Could you paste the script into your answer? If you style it as pre-formatted text, scrollbars will be added to prevent it from being too long.

Comment: Ferdi, it seems like you are posting a lot of scripts (which is great!) I would recommend though that you open a [github](https://github.com/) account and just upload your scripts there. That way people look at the scripts, download them, and even ask to improve your scripts and contribute if they see a way to make it even better.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm a web designer and I have a blog. And I'm posting useful tips about photoshop and design. So, these scripts are not written by me. If I learn one day, I'll have a github, too. :)

Comment: I've changed the link. File uploaded on dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Generator and writing something to export assets programatically? https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/wiki/Generate-Web-Assets-Functional-Spec

If you need a user interface, you can try out the Extract Assets dialog in the new version of Photoshop.