# Photoshop Batch Script for Exporting Layers with a Master Backround

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, export, photoshop-scripting, automation

I have 100 layers that I want to export with a specific master layer as the background.

Any JSX scripts out there for CS6?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An Action can be recorded to do this. It's a bit of a trick, but works.

First, Duplicate the document, and select the top layer.

This is going to be the starting point.

... then assuming you know how to record an action, record it doing the following:

1. Duplicate Document
2. Layer > Arrange > Send to Back
3. Layer > Merge Down
4. Select > All Layers
5. Layer > Delete > Layers
6. Export as you like
7. Close without Saving
8. Layer > Delete > Layer

What this does:

Creates a copy of your current document with the top layer selected, then pushes it all the way down to the bottom, just above the background Layer.

Then it merges this selected Layer with the background, then (the tricky part) exploits a slight anomaly in Photoshop layer selection when Selecting all Layers the background is NOT selected, so the next step deletes all the unneeded layers for this export.

Then it exports as you wish.

Then dispose of this "working" file.

Which automatically returns you to the starting point file, with the top layer currently selected. Which it then deletes, leaving you with the next layer selected as this is the new starting point.

Now you can either tap to play this Action 100x, or record another action that does only one things, play this Action, and then play that until it gets an error, at which point it will be finished exporting your 100 layers

Comment: it would be a lot better if this script here could be re-coded to work with a target master layer that gets exported every time  : https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-as-Images

or if the Slicy App could do that too. ( it tried but couldnt figure out how to use a master layer repeatedly )

Comment: Why can't you make the "master layer" the background layer, and work from there?

Comment: i did and it didnt work. it just exports all the layers individually.This is my setup: http://cl.ly/image/2W0i0f2X3w1K

Comment: what didn't work?

Comment: ok i just updated a better script that also works with groups and now ..master backgrounds ;-)

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/31295/4753