# How do I find out what the high level differences are between two partially different PSDs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I find out what the high level differences are between two partially different PSDs?

I can diff them as binary/text files, but I would prefer something like

```
added layer x
moved item y two pixels
changed color from a to b
```

or some graphic diff showing what is different in the different layers.

Or is there some way that I can export as PNGs or print each layer to PDF or similar? Then I would manage to diff those files.

Comment: Welcome to GD! Interesting question. Are you looking for an existing solution to do this for you (i.e. a software recommendation)?

Comment: I was hoping to get information on how I could use Photoshop to compare two Photoshop images, or to somehow export all the layers to some other non-layered format.

Comment: Honestly, never heard about such solutions. From time to time I need to do comparison (but not so detailed) and I just put images in stack and turn on "Difference" as blend method at top to see what parts are different.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool to diff images by overlaying them: http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/ Not sure if it works directly with psd, but you could give the demo a try.

Comment: I can confirm it does work with PSDs, but I think it will only show the differences between the entire composited file, not the separate layers. Exporting the layers as individual files for comparison might still work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the first part of your question, but through a quick search I was able to find these methods to "Export photoshop layers to individual PNG files - batch process?" from that previous Stack Exchange Question: [Batch export Photoshop layers to individual PNG files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process)

Question is originally for Photoshop CS4, but Method 1 still works for me using Adobe CC.