# Photoshop - Export Asset with multiple clipping masks

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, clipping-mask

How could I export all my clipping masks (the clipping masks in different colors and pattern - 32 clipping masks) in one go with a single asset/model?

My normal approach is to export manually, one by one of the clipping masks which consumes a lot of times.
When I am using the export → Layers to files → it only export out all the clipping masks without the asset/model in it.

Any work around of these?

Comment: hello and welcome GDSE. can you explain more of your question like which type of layers your psd contains and which kind of pattern of export you are talking!  Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Design Phoenix, it is a pattern layer more than 50 design pattern. My question is similar to this post link below, but it seems that the post yet to receive any solution. Thanks!https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37930/how-to-automatically-save-each-layer-as-its-own-png-jpeg-while-keeping-one-main

Comment: as far as i understand assume you have 20 clipping mask and 20 layers clipped so your layer panel are like " clipping layer - clipping mask - clipping layer - clipping mask..." right? if you won't mind can you share screenshot of your layer panel or anything related it because to make script i need the layer details etc :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I presume you have a bunch of clipping masks and a base layer and you want to export every clipping mask + the base layer as a separate png.

[image]

This script will ask for an output folder, select the top layer and then will start to save pngs, hide current clipping mask and select a layer below. Names will be `documentName_layerIndex.png`

Result:

[image]

```
function main()
{
    if (documents.length == 0) return false;

    var outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog('', new Folder(Folder.myDocuments));

    if (outputFolder == null) return false;

    var doc = activeDocument,
        docName = doc.name.split('.')[0],
        counter = 1;

    doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[0];

    while (doc.activeLayer.grouped)
    {
        saveForWebPng(outputFolder + "/" + docName + "_" + counter + ".png");
        doc.activeLayer.visible = false;
        selectPreviousLayer();
        counter++
    };

    function saveForWebPng(saveFile)
    {
        var pngOpts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb;
        pngOpts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG
        pngOpts.PNG8 = false;
        pngOpts.transparency = true;
        pngOpts.interlaced = false;
        pngOpts.quality = 100;
        activeDocument.exportDocument(new File(saveFile), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, pngOpts);
    }; // end of saveForWebPng()

    function selectPreviousLayer() {
        var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Bckw'));
        desc.putReference(cTID('null'), ref);
        desc.putBoolean(cTID('MkVs'), false);
        executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
    }; // end of selectPreviousLayer()

    function cTID(s)
    {
        return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
    };

    function sTID(s)
    {
        return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
    };


}
app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("temp", "main()");
```