# How to get the Icons from the PSD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an PSD file http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/

How to extract all the icons(png) from the psd using photoshop

Comment: what have you tried?  At this time it would almost appear like your question is spam.

Answer (score 3):

If the psd file is in separate layers, you can export them with:

File >> Scripts >> Export layers to files...

A similar answer:
[Batch export Photoshop layers to individual PNG files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process)