# Print all layers as thumbnails with their names on one page

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, actions

I want to print all layers preview on one page with the names. I 'm looking for a .atn action or other simple way to do it

Comment: Probably: [`File > Scripts > Export layers to files...`](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1962/2332) and then `File > Automate > Contact sheet II`

Comment: @Joonas that would make a good answer actually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried these scripts which inluded in CS3?

1. File > Automate > Picture Package
2. File > Automate > Web Photo Gallery
3. File > Automate > Photo Merge

These are some usefull tools to do thing like that you wanted.