# Is it possible in to export layers to separate files in Photoshop as PNG with original resolution?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, creative-cloud, ppi

Is it possible to export layers to separate files as PNG with original resolution? When I try to 'Export as' in Photoshop CC 2015 - it saves files as 72 PPI. I need to keep them as 300 PPI.

Comment: Are they actually changing in pixel size or only resolution? If the pixel size is the same then it doesn't really matter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am selling Clip-art, it is important that PNG  files have resolution 300 DPI.

Comment: My point is, assuming the same pixel size, the resolution has no effect on the image itself, its only meta data.

Comment: Thank you Cal. In description for my product I need to indicate resolution. People want to buy high resolution clip-art (300 DPI). So, I need to find a solution. I do not understand why photoshop is changing the original resolution.

Comment: Thats fair enough, makes sense. Im using CS6 so I don't know about the new export but save for web (which afaik export is meant to replace) always saves at 72ppi.. Is there any reason you can't simply "Save As" which would leave your ppi intact?

Comment: I do not 'Save for web' since it does change resolution. I use 'Export as'. It gives me options how to save, but it does not mention resolution option. I assume that it should be the original resolution saved, but unfortunately...  Technically I can save all layers manually, but when there are 70-100 layers, it is time consuming to trim each one and then save.

Comment: One of the scripts [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1961) should do the job

Comment: Unfortunately the Method 2: Custom Script - saves layers in 72 dpi as well.  Photoshop CC does not  The Built-In Script (Method 1)

Answer (score 2):

Export your images as you are at 72PPI *at the correct pixel size* then create an action to change the PPI to 300 that you can use as a batch process on the images.

1. Export your images to their own unique folder.
2. With one of your images open in Photoshop create a new Action.
3. With your new action recording, go to *Image → Image Size...*
4. Uncheck "Resample Image" and set the resolution to 300.
5. Stop recording your action.

Then...

6. Go to *File → Automate → Batch...* and select your newly recorded action. Choose the folder you exported to as the source and choose "Save and Close" as the destination.
7. Hit OK and watch Photoshop do the work for you.