# Is there a faster way to save all layers in PSD to PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, export

I'm trying to export all 155 raster layers, each 240*240 in pixels, to separate png files, but it takes ages to do that using CS5 <kbd>File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files</kbd>.

This script creates new psd files, copies all layers to them, then makes one layer visible before deleting all the layers he has just added. It took about three hours to export half of my layers.

If I was a script coder i'd make exporting this way:

```
for each layer do {
   make layer invisible }

for each layer do {
   make layer visible
   save file as "layer_name.png"
   make layer invisible }
```

Is there any faster way to export all layers to png?

Comment: your system seems having memory problem,slow performance, i did the same thing more than 200 images and it took only 10 minutes..

Comment: @Jack is correct and I would consider adjusting your performance in `Edit > Preferences > Performance` there is a `Memory Usage` Bar.

Comment: This is actually [the logic that I used in my export layers script.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1962/408)

Answer (score 16):

In the animation panel flyout menu, choose "Make frames from layers."

File > Export > Render Video. Choose a folder for the export and select "Image Sequence" and "PNG".

Comment: Is there anything you _don't_ know?

Comment: i guess it wont work..

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks for the compliment, but honestly there is so much I don't know that I often feel a bit overwhelmed. The last 3-5 years have been like living on the chessboard in Alice Through the Looking Glass: You have to run as fast as you can just to stay in the same place, and run like anything to actually get anywhere. That's true of print, web, video and the host of new platforms from iThings to digital displays/billboards to interactive kiosks to RIA platforms like Adobe Air. We're all scrambling to keep up, me no less than anyone else.

Comment: @Alan The difficulty in that task simply makes it all that more impressive. But I completely understand, I'm studying computer science, and that field as well is one where you cannot afford to fall behind. In addition to that, during the short time of you being here you've become the #1 user with nearly twice the reputation of the #2 user, that's impressive as well. Anyways, I just wanted to acknowledge that.

Comment: That's gracious of you, and I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: This is a great method but when I tried it, transparent color becomes black for each image. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: At the bottom of the dialog, there is a dropdown to select the alpha channel setting. Change it from None to Unmatted.

Comment: @Alan This is simply amazing. Thanks a million times.

Comment: @David Bert Monroy says over and over "Don't pay attention to what it's *called*, look at what it *does*. He's usually talking about Photoshop filters, but this is the same sort of thing. It's called "video," but that doesn't mean you can't use it for other things.

Comment: This only works for images of the same size.

Comment: I just tried "Make frames from layers" and it just output a bunch of blank frames and made every visible layer invisible inside my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can try MacRabbit's [Slicy App](http://macrabbit.com/slicy/) if you are working on OS X. It's really easy to use for slicing process for web development.

Answer (score 1):

**MacGyver Solution:**

Make a copy/backup from file `Export Layers to Files.jsx`, available on your Photoshop CS6 instalation folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Presets\Scripts`).

Edit the file (using notepad or whatever...) and comment/change line 940 (or use the find text tool):

```
obj.artLayers[i].remove();
```

to:

```
//obj.artLayers[i].remove();
```

Save file and use it on Photoshop. `File` > `Scripts` > `Open File/Load script`
This worked great for me. Much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone gets to this question through Google or wherever, I wanted to let you know that if the built in solution is too slow, I wrote my own script to export layers to either JPGs or PNGs that it much faster than the built-in script.

[That answer can be found here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1962/408).

[The script can be found here](https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-as-Images).

But basically it does a minimal amount of work to export layers, rather than the long and complex process Photoshop takes, therefore being much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so that there is any easy and fast way of doing so ,as alan said try that animation ,render video thing,

i would suggest you to use scripts only because they are easy to work on instead of other methods.

if you need some sort of script see this:

1. [Saving your layers as separate documents example in site](http://www.kirupa.com/motiongraphics/scripting6_2.htm)
2. [Export Layers to Files (Fast PNG version)](http://www.pretentiousname.com/ps_exportlayersfast/index.html)

---

there are some similar question on this site already asked please take a look :

1. [Export photoshop layers to individual PNG files - batch process???](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/export-photoshop-layers-to-individual-png-files-batch-process)
2. [Export Layers to Files exports only 4 png files from 100 layers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1729/export-layers-to-files-exports-only-4-png-files-from-100-layers)