# Script for exporting 200 layers to PNG stacked on top of one another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a faster way to save all layers in PSD to PNG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/is-there-a-faster-way-to-save-all-layers-in-psd-to-png)

This is my first attempt at Photoshop. I have been taking photos of my daughter for 6 months and I want to create a timelapse of my photos. Here is what I have done so far:

1. I inserted 200 photos as different layers into my photoshop document
2. then I lined up the eyes in each photo.
3. Then I took each layer one by one and exported it as a PNG with all the layers behind it showing like they are stacked. This took hours to save them all one by one.
4. Then I pulled them into Final Cut and made a 6 month timelapse in 30 seconds.
5. Here is the current rough cut, this should give you a good idea of what I trying to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=petLbaHFwlg

PROBLEM: There are a few photos I need to adjust or delete, but that essentially means **reexporting everything** by hand after I adjust. I don't want to do it all over again.

QUESTION: Is there an action script I can run to get ALL 200 photos at once with the previous layers showing behind them? Example: That means that the photo on layer 100 needs to export with the size of the frame fo the video and show layers 1-99 behind it. I want to figure out how to do the same thing that took me hours to do but automatically.

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/is-there-a-faster-way-to-save-all-layers-in-psd-to-png?lq=1

Comment: This question has been answered, not for your specific project but for the workflow you are trying to accomplish, so I'm closing this as a duplicate question.